# Deploy DACPAC without actually deploying

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a dacpac ignoring users, logins, roles etc.

As far as I can see in the documentation, the only way to create a dacpac without users, logins, roles etc is to publish it.

The only way I can think of doing this is something like

```
#Extract with permissions
SqlPackage  /Action:Extract `
            /Properties:IgnorePermissions=true `
            /Properties:VerifyExtraction=false `
            /Properties:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true `
            /TargetFile:$targetFile `
            /SourceConnectionString:$sourceConnectionString

#Deploy ignoring permissions
SqlPackage  /Action:Publish `
            /SourceFile:$targetFile `
            /TargetConnectionString:$targetConnectionString `
            /Properties:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings=true `
            /Properties:ExcludeObjectTypes="Users;Logins;RoleMembership;ServerRoles;ServerRoleMembership;DatabaseRoles;SecurityPolicies"

#Extract without permissions
SqlPackage  /Action:Extract `
            /Properties:IgnorePermissions=true `
            /Properties:VerifyExtraction=false `
            /Properties:IgnoreUserLoginMappings=true `
            /TargetFile:$targetFile `
            /SourceConnectionString:$targetConnectionString
```

Is there another way around this - I can't understand why ExcludeObjectTypes is not also in Extract - any ideas if there is a better way to do this?